# Finding all occurences of a column value that do not exist in other table in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My problem is as follows:

I have two tables: the first table has two columns (`person_id` and `account_ids` columns). Account_ids column has comma separated account IDs present:

```
Person_ID    Account_ids
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  123        000000grVA6AM,000016ILMhAO, 000000ihi4MAQ, 000000TF5MAQQ,000000TF5MAHZ
  124        000000frVA6AM,000016ILMhAO
  125        000000frVA6BC,000024ILMhJZ, 000000frXC6A,000024YTMhA
```

Second table has details about the person_id

```
Person_ID   Account_ID      Account_Name
----------------------------------------
  123       000000grVA6AM     Name1
  123       000016ILMhAO      Name2
  123       000000ihi4MAQ     Name3
  123       000000TF5MAQQ     Name4
  123       000000TF5MAHZ     Name5
  124       000016ILMhAO      Name2
  124       000000TF5MAHZ     Name5
  124       000000frVA6AM     Name6
  124       000024ILMhAO      Name7
  124       000000frVA7XZ     Name8
  125       000000frVA6BC     Name9 
  125       000024ILMhJZ      Name10
  125       000000frXC6A      Name11
  125       000024YTMhA       Name12
  125       000024IXThJY      Name13
```

I want to find all `account_ids` for each `person_id` that do not occur in Table 1 for that `Person_ID`. For example, from the above example the answer should be:

```
Person_ID   Account_ID      Account_Name
-----------------------------------------

   124      000000TF5MAHZ     Name5
   124      000024ILMhAO      Name7
   124      000000frVA7XZ     Name8
   125      000024IXThJY      Name13
```

How do I do that?

I was trying to apply the not like clause but then I did not understand how to split comma-separated values in Table 1. Please help!

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Giving Temp Table creation query so that it's easier to test:

```
CREATE TEMP table persons
( person_id int, account_id varchar(20), account_name varchar(10))

insert into persons values
 (123,       '000000grVA6AM',     'Name1');
 insert into persons values
  (123,       '000016ILMhAO',      'Name2');
  insert into persons values
  (123,       '000000ihi4MAQ',     'Name3');
  insert into persons values
  (123,       '000000TF5MAQQ',     'Name4');
  insert into persons values
  (123,       '000000TF5MAHZ',     'Name5');
  insert into persons values
  (124,      '000016ILMhAO',      'Name2');
  insert into persons values
  (124,       '000000TF5MAHZ',     'Name5');
  insert into persons values
  (124,      '000000frVA6AM',     'Name6');
  insert into persons values
  (124,       '000024ILMhAO',      'Name7');
  insert into persons values
  (124,       '000000frVA7XZ',     'Name8');
  insert into persons values
  (125,       '000000frVA6BC',     'Name9');
  insert into persons values 
  (125,       '000024ILMhJZ',      'Name10');
  insert into persons values
  (125,       '000000frXC6A',      'Name11');
  insert into persons values
  (125,       '000024YTMhA',       'Name12';
  insert into persons values
  (125,       '000024IXThJY'      'Name13');
```

For Accounts table:

```
CREATE TEMP table accounts
(person_id int, account_ids varchar(100))

insert into accounts values
(123,        '000000grVA6AM,000016ILMhAO, 000000ihi4MAQ, 000000TF5MAQQ,000000TF5MAHZ');
insert into accounts values
  (124,        '000000frVA6AM,000016ILMhAO');
insert into accounts values
  (125,        '000000frVA6BC,000024ILMhJZ, 000000frXC6A,000024YTMhA');
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Amazon Redshift or Microsoft SQL Server? Those are two very different database products

Comment: @user10096621 . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Someone with your experience on the site should know how to tag a question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Apologies, not sure how I tagged SQL Server, it's actually Redshift.

Answer (score 3):

We can try:

```
SELECT p.Person_ID, p.Account_ID, p.Account_Name
FROM persons p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accounts a
                  WHERE ',' || a.Account_ids || ',' LIKE '%,' || p.AccountID || ',%');
```

Please note that storing your accounts as CSV data in a single column is not optimal database design, because such data is not *normalized*.  In order to write the query you wanted, we had to do string olympics to check for the presence of each account in the CSV string.  Had those accounts all been on separate records, our task would have been easier.

**Edit:**

In case your CSV account data really has spaces in it, then compare using a replace which removes them first:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accounts a
                  WHERE ',' || REPLACE(a.Account_ids, ' ', '')  || ','
                        LIKE '%,' || p.AccountID || ',%');
```

Comment: Right, I agree but that comma separated column we are getting from user input field where user manually enter some information and we extract account IDs from that and store it into a column. The number of account IDs each user can input is different. i.e, one user can input 2 account IDs while other can input 3 etc.

Comment: Can you please explain what you're doing in the not exists clause. Thanks!

Comment: Is that going to find (or not find, as appropriate) the Account_ids that contain spaces around the commas?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I was assuming that whitespace was a copying error, but I have updated my answer to handle this edge case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added some spaces because this data is going to be a user input field and I wan'ted to include every possible case users can use while entering values.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your query only works if person_id, account_id combination is unique and doesn't when another person_id has the same account_id (which is possible). I've updated the question to include that case and included create temp table statements as well so that it's easier to test.

Comment: @user10096621 ...and I have reversed the voting on your question to a downvote, because you changed it after many other users have already answered.  You should fix your data model and stop storing CSV in your tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL Server 2016 or better you can use the [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function to separate the CSV values for independent tests, e.g.:

```sql
select b.*
from (
  select Person_ID, Account_ID
  from dbo.Table2
  except
  select Person_ID, trim(Value)
  from dbo.Table1
  cross apply string_split(Account_ids, N',')
) a
join dbo.Table2 b on b.Person_ID=a.Person_ID and b.Account_ID=a.Account_ID
```

Note the `trim(Value)` which discards any space characters around the Account IDs in your Account_ids column, which requires SQL Server 2017 or better, you can use `ltrim(rtrim(Value))` on earlier versions.

Comment: How do you even know the OP is using SQL Server?

Comment: We don't. But they have spam-tagged `sql-server` in amongst things.